# Xslt transformation on SOAP xml response

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am very new in using XSL ... I have a SOAP response :-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <insertDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
         <Response>Done !!!</Response>
         <Id>0</Id>
         <Age>0</Age>
      </insertDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I am using following XSL to transform the response :-

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body>
            <insertDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
                <Response>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Response" />
                </Response>
                              <Id>
                   <xsl:value-of select="Id" />
              </Id>
              <Age>
                   <xsl:value-of select="Age" />
              </Age>
            </insertDataResponse>
            </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now ... when I am trying to perform XSL transformation on the SOAP request ... I am getting the following output :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <insertDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
            <Response />
            <Id />
            <Age />
        </insertDataResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am getting without any value in the attributes ... am I doing something wrong ... am I missing something ... Please Help ...

Comment: I notice you've tagged your question "xslt-2.0" but the stylesheet you've supplied is `version="1.0"`. My answer applies equally to both versions but you should make it clear which one you actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inside a template matching `/` so the

```
<xsl:value-of select="Response" />
```

and similar expressions are looking for a *root-level* element named `Response` in no namespace, which doesn't exist (the document element is named `Envelope` and is in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace).

You would need to declare the `http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1` namespace with a prefix in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:md1="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="md1">
```

and fix up your xpaths to match the structure:

```
<xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/md1:insertDataResponse/md1:Response"/>
```

However given how similar your inputs and outputs are you might be better off structuring things differently, basing your stylesheet on the *identity transformation* instead (of which there are hundreds of examples in other questions on this site).

Comment: How to Add an additional attribute say ID in xslt that doesn't exists... can I add an additional attribute here with hard coded value ???

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary yes, I suggest you find a good beginners' tutorial for XSLT and work through that to get comfortable with the basics (make sure it's one that specifically says it's for XSLT 1.0 rather than 2.0 if that's what you need to use).